# Turn off display of header dashes in SQL Server Management Studio query results?

Tags: ssms

How can I tell SQL Server 2008 Management Studio to turn off printing of header dashes when displaying text results in a query window?

Examples of header dashes being produced are:

`selectId, count(*) ContentCount from Table group by Id order by count(*) desc` produces:

```
Id                   ContentCount
-------------------- ------------------
622                  5
623                  1
```

`select 'Person Info'` produces:

```
------------
Person Info
```

Those dashes are not conducive to all situations so I expect there is way to turn them off.

Comment: Nit pick - this is not a "SQL Server" feature. It is a "SQL Server Management Studio" feature.

Comment: Looks like this is still the right place for this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70544/ and FAQ says `software tools commonly used by programmers` http://stackoverflow.com/faq  I changed the question tag from SQL Server to Management Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto Tools, Options, Query Results.  You can change the output to Grid if you want there.  I don't see a way to turn off just the dashes in the Results to text options.  Check that - change to Comma Delimited and the dashes don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : Under Options/Query Results/SQL Server/Results to Text there is a checkbox to untick entitled 'Include column headers in the result set'.

However, I wanted to do this programmatically, as I perform a query as part of an email report that looks a mess with the headers, but haven't found out a way yet (which IS a SQL Server issue).

Comment: I don't want to get rid of the headers though, only the dashed delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

this is an incorrect SQL statement.

set head off
set und off

Comment: Please add a code block with the correct syntax. The answer will be improved and helpful.

Answer (score -8):

for a SQL query, type the following above the Select statement:

to remove the headers, type: set head off

to remove the underline, type: set und off